# Upgarding to react 18 issues in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I 'm working on a large typescript with react project and I 've decided to upgrade to react 18 new version and since I did the following
`npm install react@18`
`npm install react-dom@18`
`npm install @types/react-dom@18`
`npm install @types/react@18`
The app has been broken and got me several error while I 've resolved most of them I got more and more
for example I got this error for this code in a type script

```
  const pages = useMemo(() => {
    let page = startPage;
    const pageRange = [];
    while (page <= endPage) {
      pageRange.push(page);
      page += 1;
    }
    return pageRange;
  }, [startPage, endPage]);
```

error message `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.  TS2345`
I know the fix to assign the type to the defined array here but this pattern is repeated in the codebase , so i 'm not sure if upgrading to react 18 need some configration with type-script , i 've checked the react docs for upgrading to new react 18 but there was no mention for this .

my current typescript version is `"typescript": "^3.7.5"`

Comment: So what's your question? Please also show the exact line that shows that error. I see no parameters of type `never` in the example code...

Comment: the error is in line `const pageRange = [];` it 's solved with `const pageRange: number[] = [];`

Comment: however this declaration is repeated around the codebase , so i 'm not sure what 's causing this break in react@18

Comment: Are you sure you only updated React and not e.g. TypeScript or its version?

Comment: Yup sure , I 've checked the package.json file and I only see react and react dom have been changed

Comment: Well, then I'd say `useMemo`'s signature has become stricter in the React 18 types, which means you can't ust return _anything_ out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my `package.json` solved the problem

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

source : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1094565891